# SQL query to search books based on tags, with right ordering and tag priority

Tags: mysql, sql

I've learned basic CRUD operations, but now I am studying JOINS and more complicated MySQL queries, and I am struggling.

Here are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
title VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE books_tags(
book_id INT NOT NULL,
tag_id INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (book_id, tag_id)
);
```

What I have so far (probably not working properly):

```
SELECT b.title
FROM books_tags bk1, books_tags bk2, books b
WHERE bk1.tag_id = TAG1 OR
      bk1.tag_id = TAG2 AND
      bk1.tag_id = bk2.tag_id AND
      b.id = bk2.book_id
GROUP BY bk2.book_id;
```

What I want:

- A query to search books by tags
- Books with most matching tags are first
- Some tags can have different "importance" (not really important for now, not sure if possible)

Comment: example data would help greatly

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7ce56/4

Comment: @DarkSide ^ there is some example data... I would love to get a list of books, which are creepy/scary. Creepy AND scary should be first, then creepy, then scary.

Comment: I see, so first should be books which have the most different tags applied? And if so, then simple `SELECT books.*, (select count(*) from books_tags WHERE book_id=books.id) AS weigth FROM books;` can do?

Comment: @DarkSide The tags are dynamically supplied. First should be books that have most matching tags

Comment: @DarkSide edited my question to make more sense. I want a query that searches books by tags, books with most matching tags are first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query will search books by more than one tag name and orders it by *most matching tags* in decreasing order. That means, books with more matching tags will be first.

```
SELECT
     b.id
    ,b.title
    ,count(1) AS tag_count
    ,group_concat(t.name) AS tags
FROM books b
    JOIN books_tags bt ON bt.book_id=b.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id=bt.tag_id
WHERE t.name IN ('scary', 'creepy')
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
ORDER BY tag_count DESC;
```

Sample data:

```
INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, "Dracula");
INSERT INTO books VALUES(2, "Frankenstein");
INSERT INTO books VALUES(3, "Screenburn");

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, "scary");
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, "creepy");
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, "funny");

INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (3, 3);
```

Output:

```
ID  TITLE           TAG_COUNT   TAGS
1   Dracula         2           scary,creepy
2   Frankenstein    1           scary
```

---

And here is full example with tag priority implemented too:

```
CREATE TABLE books (
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  title VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE tags (
  id INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
  priority INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE books_tags(
  book_id INT NOT NULL,
  tag_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (book_id, tag_id)
);

INSERT INTO books VALUES(1, "Dracula");
INSERT INTO books VALUES(2, "Frankenstein");
INSERT INTO books VALUES(3, "Screenburn");
INSERT INTO books VALUES(4, "Kitten story");

INSERT INTO tags VALUES (1, 1, "scary");
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (2, 3, "creepy");
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (3, 2, "funny");
INSERT INTO tags VALUES (4, 1, "useless");

INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (1, 1),(1, 2);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (3, 2),(3, 3);
INSERT INTO books_tags VALUES (4, 3),(4, 4);
```

Selecting:

```
SELECT
     b.id
    ,b.title
    ,group_concat(t.name) AS matching_tags
    ,count(1) AS tag_count
    ,sum(t.priority) AS priority
FROM books b
    JOIN books_tags bt ON bt.book_id=b.id
    JOIN tags t ON t.id=bt.tag_id
WHERE t.name IN ('scary', 'creepy', 'funny')
GROUP BY b.id, b.title
ORDER BY priority DESC;
```

Output:

```
ID  TITLE           MATCHING_TAGS   TAG_COUNT   PRIORITY
3   Screenburn      creepy,funny    2           5 (because 3+2)
1   Dracula         scary,creepy    2           4 (because 1+3)
4   Kitten story    funny           1           2 (because 2)
2   Frankenstein    scary           1           1 (because 1)
```

Comment: Basically, I want to search for books based on MORE tags. If a book matches more of those specified tags, it should be ranked higher than a one that matches ONE tag.

Comment: Updated my answer with SELECT for tags priority too and also using group_concat to easily see which tags was applied.

Comment: I meant query tags priority, like you can specify how much a tag in the search matters, but anyway thanks - you are a beast!

I will try to earn some reputation so I can upvote you :)

Comment: Well, I guess you can make some changes in SELECT quite easily to set tags priority at query time. Idea is the same - use SUM() to sum tag priorities together.

Comment: Yep, I think I need to create a 'virtual' table with tags that are matched, and a 2priority tag should have 2 rows, and then sum those... However I will not do this until I learn more SQL :)